# javascript could not achieve the return

Tags: javascript, return

I had made this function, and this is new yet, and I don't really know how to handle this roughly.

```
var $;
(function() {
$ = function(e) {
    return new query(e);
};

var query = function(e) {
    var e = document.querySelectorAll(e), i;
    for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        this[i] = e[i];
    }

    this.length = e.length;
    return this;
};
$.fn.prototype = {
    hide: function() {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
        return this;
    },
    hasClass: function (klass) {
        var e = this, i;
        var t = [];

        for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            var k = e[i].className;
            var array = k.split(' ');
            // If the element has the class, add it for return
            if (array.indexOf(klass) > -1) {
                t.push(e[i]);
            }
        }
        // Return the list of matched elements
        return t;
    }
}
} ());

window.onload = function() {
$(".element").hasClass("someClass").hide();
}
```

So yeah, that's the code above. I think I have matched the class, but what the problem is, It's not returning the elements. I'm new to prototyping so please don't be harsh. I really need to fix this one. Please don't tell me to go and have jquery. I don't want to use that massive library just because I want some css selectors.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do, what you expect to happen, and what's really happening, so could you clarify your question?

Comment: I want the element having the class `someClass` to be hidden but it's not working. It's not returning the elements.  but really it's working with the other function when using `return this`. I want to pass the elements from the `t=[]` but sadly, it does not return what i want. hope you could understand. I'm sorry im not really good in english

Comment: use sizzle,sizzle is a core of jquery,but includes only 'getElement' part http://sizzlejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the function isn't the current element.

```
hasClass: function (klass) {
        var e = this, i;
        var t = [];

        for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            var k = e[i].className;
            var array = k.split(' ');
            // If the element has the class, add it for return
            if (array.indexOf(klass) > -1) {
                t.push(e[i]);
            }
        }
        // Return the list of matched elements
        return t;
    }
```

and that is why your script do not return the element.

ALSO:

You tried to use jQuery's method to add your own functions in library, but actually this will not work, as you're writing pure js, not jquery, and you need to do many thing to make it work like jQuery.

```
$.fn.prototype = {
    hide: function() {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
        return this;
    },
    hasClass: function (klass) {
        var e = this, i;
        var t = [];

        for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            var k = e[i].className;
            var array = k.split(' ');
            // If the element has the class, add it for return
            if (array.indexOf(klass) > -1) {
                t.push(e[i]);
            }
        }
        // Return the list of matched elements
        return t;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: no, it's the current element. I just want to pass the new filtered elements which has the class `someClass` and is stored `t=[]` array.

Comment: @Hazmat already answered this question. Thanks anyways. I know there are better libraries out there but I want to have my own. Merry Christmas here from phillippines . :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is this line: `$.fn.prototype = {};`.  There is no `$.fn` in your code *anywhere*, so you cannot set a `prototype` property on it.  (In jQuery, `$.fn` is set to `jQuery.prototype`, that's why you can set `$.fn.someMethod`.)

If you want the `hasClass` method to exists on *your* objects, you need to modify the `prototype` of `query`.  Your `$` function returns `new query` objects, so `query` is where the `hasClass` method should be.

Also, your `hasClass` method returns an *array*.  Arrays do not have a method called `hide`.  You need to have your `hasClass` method return a `query` object, so that you can continue to chain methods.

P.S. Shouldn't a `hide` method set the `style.display` to `'none'`?

Anyway, your code should look like this:

```js
var $;
(function() {
  $ = function(e) {
    return new query(e);
  };

  var query = function(e) {
    var e = Array.isArray(e) ? e : document.querySelectorAll(e),
      i;
    for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
      this[i] = e[i];
    }

    this.length = e.length;
    return this;
  };
  query.prototype = {
    hide: function() {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        this[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
      return this;
    },
    hasClass: function(klass) {
      var e = this,
        i;
      var t = [];

      for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        var k = e[i].className;
        var array = k.split(' ');
        // If the element has the class, add it for return
        if (array.indexOf(klass) > -1) {
          t.push(e[i]);
        }
      }
      // Return the list of matched elements
      return new query(t);
    }
  }
}());

window.onload = function() {
  $(".element").hasClass("someClass").hide();
}
```

```html
<p class="someClass element">You can't see me!</p>
```

(Note: [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) doesn't work in IE < 9.)

Comment: sorry. :) .. didn't see that .. thanks.. I'll try this. I have included that on my post that i'm new to prototyping yet. I'll need some pro to really explain me this kind of stuff. btw, I've just read this from John Resig's book

Comment: wait, is it necessary to use a `new query(t)` or could i just now call the function `query(t)` ?

Comment: @johnpaulcalvo: You need the `new` keyword, so that you are creating a new object.  Otherwise, `this` will not be what you think.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to query for elements matching a condition and hide it based on element type, id or class name CSS query selectors along with querySelector() or querySelectorAll() api.

For your code sample the same can be rewritten as below

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("element.someClass");
for(var i = 0; i <elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```